# Electronic bicycling ranking for the office cyclists?

Tags: road-bike

in the office many of us cycle to work. We though it would be cool to have ranking of cyclists with different sorting (distance, avg. speed and such). We can track our trips with Android or iPhone apps (like Strava Cycling).

We are mostly developers, so if we find a tool or device that can easily display a ranking (per week, month, all time) we can use the tools to track our trips and compete with each other :) Can you suggest something that might work?

Comment: This is off topic here, consider asking this on Stackoverflow or Programmers (not sure if it is on tipic there, tough).

Comment: I'd disagree. Questions about building a tool, or using a web API, would be better there (or perhaps  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but I think asking other cyclists if they have recommendations fits here.

(You could just create a shared spreadsheet in Google Docs. Strava sounds a nicer solution though.)

Comment: I also disagree, and it would definitely be off topic on StackOverflow and Programmers.

Answer (score 6):

Strava has an [API](https://stravasite-main.pbworks.com/w/page/51754108/Strava%20API%20v2%20Overview) so if you all use it to log your rides, you could pull the data for each rider and do any analysis you want.

There are heaps of people (including me) using the API for additional statistics and analysis.

Comment: We have to somehow group the office workers so we can use API against only our group. It seems there are no groups :(

Comment: You mean like [clubs](https://stravasite-main.pbworks.com/w/page/51754142/Strava%20REST%20API%20Method%3A%20clubs%20members)?

Comment: If you decide not to use groups, you can still have a list of user IDs, and use the somewhat hidden "streams" of Strava API v1, like this one from one of my commutes (JSON) format: http://app.strava.com/api/v1/streams/20980327 (you have to query via user ID in order to get ride codes, and then get the streams of each ridecode).

Comment: @Veseliq If you collect the rider IDs of the people in your office, your code can only query those riders. You don't need a group in Strava if you can implement it yourself.

Comment: @Veseliq what language are you and your colleagues most familiar with? I have some C# .Net code I can share if you want.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question was asked, strava has added *club* feature, in fact there's a [bicycles.se club](https://www.strava.com/clubs/181338).

Comment: As this old thread is bumped, and doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure clubs existed when the question was asked, as I linked to the API spec in a comment at the time :)

Comment: @Useless possibly, I didn't use Strava back then